# I am trying to use .click function with jquery and it is not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to active .click on something and it's just not working.

example
HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="food">
```

js :

```
$('#food').click( () => {
    console.log('working');
})
```

I tried to use addeventlister without jquery and I am getting this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at script.js:11

code :

```
const foodEL = document.getElementById('food');
foodEL.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    console.log('working');
})
```

try it
https://github.com/Dor-Elisha/RecipeSearcher.git

Comment: You are running your code before the element exists, hence why you get the error when using addEventListener. jQuery doesn't error out when it doesn't find the element

Comment: Try to move the `<script>` section to the end of the `<body>` except jQuery.

Comment: Another fix around this problem is to wrap the contents of your `script.js` into `$(function() {  /* your code here */ });` (shorthand for [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)). If you use this wrapper, the code will be executed when the entire page DOM has been parsed, and your `<input>` is part of DOM at that point.